# How do I add a new column, and fill in the variables based on another columns variable in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'd appreciate any help I can get here.

I have a dataset that I've created, and I need to take the "Total Return Change" variable from the table "spReturns" based on the year of the return, and append it as a new column in "relativeTable". The catch is, that each return needs to be appended with the equal "year" in "relativeTable". So, for example, each observation in relativeTable with the "year" 1989, should have a new column of the return that matches the "Total Return Change". In this instance, every "year" of 1989 should have the return of 0.1661, from 1989 in the "spReturn" table. I'm totally clueless how to go about this, so I appreciate any help I can get.

```
require(Quandl)
require(lubridate)
require(zoo)
require(xts)

myData <- load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))
myData <- myData

year <- gss$year
finSat <- gss$satfin

relativeTable <- data.frame(year, finSat)
relativeTable <- subset(relativeTable, year > "1988" & !is.na(finSat))


spReturns <- Quandl("SANDP/ANNRETS", trim_start="1970-01-11", 
                    trim_end="2012-12-31", authcode="nwy3a_Gmd7TSS9fVirxT", 
                    collapse="annual")

percentChange <- spReturns$"Total Return Change"

spReturns$"Year Ending" <- format((spReturns$"Year Ending"), "%Y")
spReturns$"Year Ending" <- as.numeric(spReturns$"Year Ending")
spReturns$"Year Ending" <- spReturns[,1] + 1 #the following year
```

Comment: More specifically, `merge(relativeTable, spReturns[,c(1,5)], by.x="year", by.y="Year Ending")`

Answer (score 1):

```
combined <- merge(relativeTable, spReturns, by.x = "year", by.y = "Year Ending")
```